# i am having problems understanding this code, can someone help me explicitly explain it, expecially " while (size--) & tmp = (int *)&node->n;"

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * struct listint_s - Doubly linked list node
 *
 * @n: Integer stored in the node
 * @prev: Pointer to the previous element of the list
 * @next: Pointer to the next element of the list
 */
typedef struct listint_s // generating a structure
{
    const int n;
    struct listint_s *prev;
    struct listint_s *next;
} listint_t;

/**
 * create_listint - Creates a doubly linked list from an array of integers
 *
 * @array: Array to convert to a doubly linked list
 * @size: Size of the array
 *
 * Return: Pointer to the first element of the created list. NULL on failure
 */
listint_t *create_listint(const int *array, size_t size)
{
    listint_t *list;
    listint_t *node;
    int *tmp;

    list = NULL;
    while (size--)
    {
        node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        if (!node)
            return (NULL);
        tmp = (int *)&node->n;
        *tmp = array[size];
        node->next = list;
        node->prev = NULL;
        list = node;
        if (list->next)
            list->next->prev = list;
    }
    return (list);
}
```

I am having difficulty understanding these lines of code

```
while (size--)
```

and

```
tmp = (int *)&node->n;
```

When will the code exit the while loop, also i really want to understand how this piece of code works.

Comment: also i don't understand this line of code "list->next->prev = list;" from the code. i need an explicit explanation

Answer (score 1):

Within the structure

```
typedef struct listint_s // generating a structure
{
    const int n;
    struct listint_s *prev;
    struct listint_s *next;
} listint_t;
```

the data member `n` is declared with the qualifier `const`. So you may not directly assign to it a value like for example

```
node->n = array[size];
```

The compiler will issue an error saying that you are trying to change a constant object.

So there is used a trick. At first there is declared a pointer to the object as a pointer to a non-constant object

```
int *tmp;
```

and this pointer is assigned with the address of the data member `node->n` using casting

```
tmp = (int *)&node->n;
```

The casting is required because the expression `&node->n` has the type `const int *`

And then using the pointer tmp a value is assigned to the constant object

```
*tmp = array[size];
```

As for this while loop

```
while (size--)
```

the it iterates while the number of elements in the array is not equal to 0. You may rewrite the while loop like

```
while ( size-- != 0 )
```

The function adds new elements in the beginning of the list storing in it values of the passed array starting from the last element of the array and down to the first element of the array. .

Pay attention to that the function is unsafe. It can produce memory leaks if some node will not be dynamically allocated due to this if statement

```
    node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (!node)
        return (NULL);
```